# How to turn on area-learning during motion-tracking?

Tags: google-project-tango

I'm new of tango development. And I have applyed for the certificate of tango's vps(Visual Positioning Service) ,but there is no response unfortunately.

For now, How I can run motion-tracking without drifting? I mean I don't like to take my tango device walking around the room to learn the area and generate adf files, or loading any descriptions previous learned.

Is there any approach to learn and save scene feature points during tracking ,just as the slam does?
I have watched the talk of google I/O 2016, and found the point:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NTZZCtmR3OY

[screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0l8W.png)

Dose it work?

Comment: You are not forced to save the ADF file at all, so you can just launch your application with AreaLearning functionality and start learning a new ADF everytime. This will allow your app to do drift corrections and loop closures, but in the end, just don't save the ADF file.

The info that you need to do that are in this tuto https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/unity/unity-howto-area-learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the GameObject where you have attached TangoApplication Script. If you look at Inspection you get an option called Pose Mode. There you can set it to area learning mode. This is answered on assumption you use Unity Game Engine. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aMgT.png)

Comment: thanks, I'm not familiar with unity. Is there any implementation under C language [JNI ]?

Comment: Sorry. I haven't used it. Please checkout the examples on Tango developer website.